# Assigning values from Link button to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am using datagrid. Here is the code for datagrid

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Width="800px">
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
        <headerstyle width="100px"></headerstyle>
        <headertemplate>
            View
        </headertemplate>
        <itemtemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton HeaderText="View" ID="View" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'  DataField="View" runat="server" OnClick = "EditItem"/>
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I have written a method in my code behind.

```
protected void EditItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);

    string yourValue = btn.CommandArgument;

    string a = yourValue;
    string ab = "L0006.jpg";

    //  string b = Path.Combine("", a);

    this.myPDFiFrame.Attributes["src"] = Path.Combine("NoticeFile/", ab);
}
```

I want to get the selected value from the link to assign into string "yourValue". Don't know why is always showing Null.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:DataGrid  ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" Width = "800px" >



<asp:TemplateColumn>
                  <HeaderStyle Width="100px"></HeaderStyle>
                  <HeaderTemplate>
                   View
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton HeaderText="View" ID="View" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Name") %>' CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Name") %>'  DataField="View" runat="server" OnClick = "EditItem"/>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

I have added `commndargument` attribute.